# List of date with hours between two dates

Tags: python, datetime

I'd like to create a list of date with hours increment, something like this :

```
['2012060100', '2012060101', '2012060102', '2012060103', '2012060104', '2012060105', '2012060106', '2012060107', '2012060108', '2012060109', '2012060110', '2012060111', '2012060112', '2012060113', '2012060114', '2012060115', '2012060116', '2012060117', '2012060118', '2012060119', '2012060120', '2012060121', '2012060122', '2012060123', '2012060200', '2012060201', '2012060202'... '2012083122', '2012083123']
```

I'm trying something like this :

```
deb = '20120601'
fin = '20120831'

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(deb, "%Y%m%d")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(fin, "%Y%m%d")

date_lst = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, ((end-start).days)+1)]

date_list = [dt.strftime("%Y%m%d") for dt in date_lst]
```

But it print only a list of dates between `start` and `end` like this :

```
['20120601', '20120602', '20120603', '20120604', ... , '20120830', '20120831']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only increment by days instead of hours. Try this.

```
deb = '20120601'
fin = '20120831'

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(deb, "%Y%m%d")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(fin, "%Y%m%d")

dif = int((end-start).total_seconds()/3600) ## time difference in hours

date_list = [(start + datetime.timedelta(hours=x)).strftime("%Y%m%d%H") for x in range(dif+1)]
```

Comment: @Phlegyas  what is the difference with you desired output?

Comment: Spronk : It's exactly what I want ! Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: The output is missing the last 23 items.

Answer (score 6):

If you want hours, you need to include `'%H'` in the format string.  You also aren't going to get hours if you add `timedelta`s that are in units of days.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta

deb = '20120601'
fin = '20120831'

start = dt.strptime(deb, "%Y%m%d")
end = dt.strptime(fin, "%Y%m%d") + timedelta(days=1)

def hour_range(start, end):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += timedelta(hours=1)

date_list = [h.strftime('%Y%m%d%H') for h in hour_range(start, end)]
```

Comment: I like your method and I'll save this for a future code ;) Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

You don't increment by hours:

```
date_lst = [start + datetime.timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(0, 24*((end-start).days)+1)]
date_list = [dt.strftime("%Y%m%d%H") for dt in date_lst]
```